# How do I convert async task/ rx java code to rxjava2?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-android, rx-java2

I tried converting my `AsyncTask` code below to `Rxjava2`, but apparently `Rxjava2` doesn't deal with null values and hence my app crashes. Here's my code for `AsyncTask`:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
                    Participant participant = entry.getValue();
                    participant.release();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
            }
        }.execute();
```

And here's the converted code to `Rxjava` (NOT `Rxjava2`) :

```
 Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Void> call() {
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
                Participant participant = entry.getValue();
                participant.release();
            }
            return Observable.just(null);
        }
    }).doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe();
```

What would be the best approach to convert it to `Rxjava` without it crashing  on returning null. Also, how does the .execute() play with respect to `Rxjava2`? not sure if that even works in `Rxjava`?

Here's the crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxComputationThreadPool-3

                                                                           io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: null ObservableSource supplied
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:74)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onError(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:63)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.EmptyDisposable.error(EmptyDisposable.java:63)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDefer.subscribeActual(ObservableDefer.java:35)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null ObservableSource supplied
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDefer.subscribeActual(ObservableDefer.java:32)
                                                                               at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842) 
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96) 
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38) 
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: It's not clear what here is null. Add stacktrace please

Comment: Please post your stack trace, aslo you need to add .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) too.

Comment: I will post it shortly. Also, return Observable.just(null); is this allowed in rxjava 2?

Comment: thanks @Geros , please check out the crash log guys.(just edited my question above). Also, is there a better approach to convert my origiinal asynctask code to rxjava 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {
                Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
                   Participant participant = entry.getValue();
                   participant.release();
                }
                return Completable.complete().toObservable();
            }
        }).doOnComplete(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
                Log.d("Complete", "Complete");
            }
        })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
```

This code will work too. Calling subscribe() method will start the job.

Comment: is there no other way without using completeable to fix my code and get it to work? I tried adding subscribeon(androidschedulers.mainthread()) but that caused item is null crash. There must be a way to improve what i already have right?

Comment: You can replace Completeable of the above code with Observable<Void>

Comment: I cant really use cb outside the function in somethingdone as it is a part of the main function Callback<Void> cb inside which I am calling the observable. Cant I use everything in one place like I am currently doing, but with some form of error handling inside? it throws error not handled exception and item is null often.also how do i convert .execute() in my asyntask to rx?

Comment: keep getting this : io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The item is null
                                                                               at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept

Comment: thanks! this seems to work, however just out of curiosity, what advantages does rxjava 2 have over the previous rxjava or even asynctask per say? will it improve my app performance?

Comment: also do i need to unsubscribe somewhere?

Comment: I can only differentiate AsyncTask over RxJava. AsyncTasks by default, use single thread pool, so when you execute multiple asynctasks, the first one will play while the others are queued, just like a media player. The app performance still the same, imo. You can still create your own thread pool just to run multiple asynctasks at the same time. You will have to manage it by your own while Rx has different schedulers.

Comment: Unsubscribing, I say call it if `doOnComplete()` handler touches activities, fragments and those screens are destroyed to avoid memory leaks as possible, also null errors.

Comment: thanks Geros! The explaination and solution is very useful.I also have a similar question after this conversion, but to a different camera function. Here's the question. Should be something simple I am missing out on,possibly one or 2 lines. any clue? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796584/rxjava-2-exception-with-camera

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have values to post back to the main thread, you can use `Completable`:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> {
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
        Participant participant = entry.getValue();
        participant.release();
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(
    () -> {
         cb.event(new Spin.Event<Void>());
    }, 
    error -> { /* show error toast */ }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {

 //This method is replacing doInBackground
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {  
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Participant>> entries = pool.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Participant> entry : entries) {
               Participant participant = entry.getValue();
               participant.release();
            }
            return Completable.complete().toObservable();
        }
    }).doOnComplete(new Action() {
     //This is onPostExecute
        @Override 
        public void run() throws Exception {
            Log.d("Complete", "Complete");
        }
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe()
```