# Rxjava 2 exception with camera

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I just switched my code from `asynctask` to `rxjava2` and I'm randomly getting this exception on my nexus:

> Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called in Galaxy s6
>   Edge

Following is my code-

Class **Camera**:

```
 public class Cameras {


    private static final String TAG = Cameras.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String SP_CAMERA_ID = "camera_id";

    private static final int NO_NEXT_TASK = 0;

    private static final int NEXT_TASK_RELEASE_COMPLETE = 1;

    private static final int NEXT_TASK_SWITCH_COMPLETE = 2;

    private static final int NEXT_TASK_START_PREVIEW = 3;


    private Camera camera;

    private int currentCameraId = -1;


    private Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback;

    private byte[] buffer1, buffer2, buffer3;

    private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;


    private Listener listener;


    public interface Listener {

        void onCameraOpened(Camera.Size size, int angle);
    }

    private boolean cameraReleased = false;


    public Cameras(Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback, Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.previewCallback = previewCallback;
        this.currentCameraId = Spin.INSTANCE.getSp().getInt(SP_CAMERA_ID, -1);
        getCameraList();
    }


    private void getCameraList() {
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        Camera.CameraInfo camInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, camInfo);
            cams.add(camInfo.facing);
        }

        if (Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK != currentCameraId
                && Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT != currentCameraId) {
            currentCameraId = cams.get(cams.size() == 2 ? 1 : 0);
        }

    }



    public boolean isSwitchCamAvailable() {
        return Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1;
    }



    public void open(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        this.surfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
        init(NEXT_TASK_START_PREVIEW);
    }



    private void init(final int nextTask) {

        if (cams.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(Spin.getContext(), "Device have no camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        cameraReleased = false;

        if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
            Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return Completable.complete().toObservable();
                }
            }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                initComplete(nextTask);
                Log.d("Complete", "Complete");
            })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();



        } else {
            try {

                synchronized (this) {
                    this.camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
                }
                initComplete(nextTask);
            } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {

            }
        }
    }



    private void initComplete(int nextTask) {
        if (camera == null) {
            return;
        }

        //noinspection SynchronizeOnNonFinalField
        synchronized (camera) {

            try {

                Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                Camera.Size size = getClosestFrameSize(params, 640);
                params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(previewCallback);

                int bufferSize = size.width * size.height
                        * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21) / 8;


                buffer1 = new byte[bufferSize];
                buffer2 = new byte[bufferSize];
                buffer3 = new byte[bufferSize];

                camera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer1);
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer2);
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer3);

                camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);

                int angle = rotateStream();

                camera.setDisplayOrientation(angle);

                if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT && angle > 0)
                    angle = 360 - angle;

                listener.onCameraOpened(size, angle);

                routNextTask(nextTask);

            } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    private Camera.Size getClosestFrameSize(Camera.Parameters params, int width) {

        Camera.Size result = null;

        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        Camera.Size currentSize = null;
        int closestDistance = 0;
        int currentDistance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); ++i) {

            if (null == result) {
                result = sizes.get(i);
                closestDistance = Math.abs(result.width - width);
                continue;
            }

            currentSize = sizes.get(i);
            currentDistance = Math.abs(currentSize.width - width);

            if (currentDistance < closestDistance) {
                closestDistance = currentDistance;
                result = currentSize;
                if (closestDistance == 0) break;
            }

        }

        return result;

    }



    public void stopPreview() {
        stopPreview(NO_NEXT_TASK);
    }

    private String nextTaskStr(final int nextTask) {
        String nextTaskStr = null;
        switch (nextTask) {
            case NO_NEXT_TASK:
                nextTaskStr = "NO_NEXT_TASK";
                break;
            case NEXT_TASK_RELEASE_COMPLETE:
                nextTaskStr = "NEXT_TASK_RELEASE_COMPLETE";
                break;
            case NEXT_TASK_SWITCH_COMPLETE:
                nextTaskStr = "NEXT_TASK_SWITCH_COMPLETE";
                break;
            case NEXT_TASK_START_PREVIEW:
                nextTaskStr = "NEXT_TASK_START_PREVIEW";
                break;
        }
        return nextTaskStr;
    }


    private void stopPreview(final int nextTask) {


        if (null == camera) return;

        if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
            Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {

                    synchronized (this) {
                        if ( (null != camera) && (!cameraReleased) ) {
                            if (LogDog.isEnabled)  ;
                            camera.stopPreview();
                        }
                    }
                    return Completable.complete().toObservable();
                }
            }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                routNextTask(nextTask);
                Log.d("Complete", "Complete");
            })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();


        } else {

            synchronized (this) {
                if ( (null != camera) && (!cameraReleased) ) {

                    camera.stopPreview();
                }
            }
            routNextTask(nextTask);
        }
    }

    private void routNextTask(int nextTask) {

        if (NO_NEXT_TASK == nextTask) return;

        if (NEXT_TASK_SWITCH_COMPLETE == nextTask) {
            switchCamComplete();
        } else if (NEXT_TASK_RELEASE_COMPLETE == nextTask) {
            releaseComplete();
        } else if (NEXT_TASK_START_PREVIEW == nextTask) {
            startPreview(null);
        }
    }

    public void startPreview(Camera.PreviewCallback cpc) {


        if (null == camera) return;
        synchronized (this) {


            camera.startPreview();
            switchCamOnAir = false;
        }
    }


    private void releaseCamera() {
        synchronized (this) {

            if (null == camera) return;
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            cameraReleased = true;
        }
    }


    public void release() {

        synchronized (this) {
            if (null == camera) return;
            stopPreview(NEXT_TASK_RELEASE_COMPLETE);
        }
    }


    private void releaseComplete() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (camera != null) {

                camera.release();
                cameraReleased = true;
                camera = null;
            }
        }
        buffer1 = null;
        buffer2 = null;
        buffer3 = null;
    }



    private boolean switchCamOnAir = false;


    public void switchCam() {
        if (!isSwitchCamAvailable()) return;
        if (null == camera) return;
        if (switchCamOnAir) return;
        this.switchCamOnAir = true;
        stopPreview(NEXT_TASK_SWITCH_COMPLETE);
    }


    private void switchCamComplete() {

        releaseCamera();

        if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        } else {
            currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        }

        Spin.INSTANCE.getSp().edit().putInt(SP_CAMERA_ID, currentCameraId).apply();

        init(NEXT_TASK_START_PREVIEW);
    }


    public int rotateStream() {

        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(currentCameraId, info);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) Spin.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        int rotation = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;

        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        return result;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public int getDeviceDefaultOrientation() {

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) Spin.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        Configuration config = Spin.getContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

        int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        if (((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) &&
                config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                || ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) &&
                config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)) {
            return Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            return Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
    }

}
```

**cameras.java**:

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
            Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {
                    if (LogDog.isEnabled) LogDog.e("Debug::"+TAG + "::stopPreview()::AsyncTask::doInBackground()", " (camera != null) =" + (camera != null) );
                    synchronized (this) {
                        if ( (null != camera) && (!cameraReleased) ) {
                            if (LogDog.isEnabled)  LogDog.e("Debug::" + TAG + "::stopPreview()::AsyncTask::doInBackground()", " XXX CALL camera.stopPreview()");
                            camera.stopPreview();
                        }
                    }
                    return Completable.complete().toObservable();
                }
            }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                routNextTask(nextTask);
                Log.d("Complete", "Complete");
            })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas where I can release the camera or allocate it, so it works without any issues?
Exception is as follows:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Camera is
>   being used after Camera.release() was called
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:74)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera is being used after
>   Camera.release() was called
>                                                                                    at android.hardware.Camera._stopPreview(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.hardware.Camera.stopPreview(Camera.java:730)
>                                                                                    at com.media.video.Cameras$2.call(Cameras.java:413)
>                                                                                    at com.media.video.Cameras$2.call(Cameras.java:406)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDefer.subscribeActual(ObservableDefer.java:32)
>                                                                                    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
>                                                                                    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38)
>                                                                                    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: Please add some debug logs when #releaseComplete() / #startPreview() / #stopPreview() / init() is being called. After this, provoke an exception and post the traces.

Comment: Its random. tried to reproduce this crash but very hard to repro, happens randomly. also I have a couple of debug logs in my code, but didn't post it here as it would have made the file bigger and usually people have the TLDR mentality so probably wounldt look at it.

Comment: Do you have at least a stacktrace?

Comment: I dont unfortunately right now But is there anything that purports to what i may be doing wrong that brings up that crash/exception?

Comment: In my opinion, it looks like a threading issue. In init you are subscribing on a background-thread, when executing on ui-thread. Therefore the subscription will happen on computational-threadpool. In the observable you synchronize on 'this'. This 'this' is the this of the 'Callable', not of the Cameras object. Same applies for stopPreview. That said, it could be, that stopPreview is called from a different thread right before init() is called. This would be a classical race-condition, because both methods use another object to sync against. The access to the camera object is not synchronized.

Comment: Hi, would be helpful how an instance of this class used by posting Activity or a fragment that uses this class.

Comment: I think that your problem with the variable nextStep, you must be sure that when you finish using your camera, it's released and you never call it before you initiate it again

Comment: Fakher how do I modify the above code to reflect that

Comment: @Geros added the exception that i finally was able to repro, any idea about it?

Comment: What's on line 413 of `Cameras`? your stack says the error is : `Cameras$2.call(Cameras.java:413)`

Comment: there's: camera.stopPreview(); on cameras.java line 413. I posted the block of code in the question to better explain the function

Comment: Could you post the LogDog logs too? Pleas use synchronized (camera) instead of synchronized (this) in "ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception". You sync against the Callable.

Comment: sure. but synchronized (camera) leads to synchronization against non final field issue , is it a viable option to turn camera into a final field? which is currently :     private Camera camera;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote for releasing the camera is prone to have race-conditions. A small change which could already make a difference is setting the flag before the action happens.

```
cameraReleased = true;
camera.release();
camera = null;
```

It might be necessary to recheck the flag just before the release of the `Camera`, but for this you *synchronized* the code before. In this context the issue is, that you're calling `synchronized(this)` within the deferred `Observable`. Instead you should synchronize on the same instance like everywhere else, because `this` doesn't refer to the outer class. Instead use `this@Cameras`

```
@Override
public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {
    if (LogDog.isEnabled) LogDog.e("Debug::"+TAG + "::stopPreview()::AsyncTask::doInBackground()", " (camera != null) =" + (camera != null) );
    synchronized (this@Cameras) {
        if ( (null != camera) && (!cameraReleased) ) {
            if (LogDog.isEnabled)  LogDog.e("Debug::" + TAG + "::stopPreview()::AsyncTask::doInBackground()", " XXX CALL camera.stopPreview()");
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
    }
    return Completable.complete().toObservable();
}
```

Additional to this, you're use-case for `Observable.defer()` doesn't look right. The [`Completable.fromAction()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromAction-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) factory might be more suitable.